# How do I reference letters when explaining my characters' accents?

Tags: word-choice

Sorry if the question is confusing. Didn't know how to phrase it 100% right. Basically, I wanna write in my novel something like:

> He had a thick accent on his Hs.

How do I write that? That the character has a thick accent on the letter H. Should I write 'H's, 'Hs', Hs, *H*s, or something different? And please don't change the format of the sentence, nor turn the "H" into singular.

Comment: Thanks :D! That answers my questions! Is there a way to link the answer on that post to this question here, or do I delete my questions, or what do you think I should do?

Comment: The end of *Danny, The Champion Of The World* by Roald Dahl has a character, Sargent Enoch Samways, who does something very funny related to H sounds and Dahl describes it in the text and also changed the spelling of Samways' dialog to reflect it. I don't have it handy for quoting but you might check it out. It is a delightful character trait for an otherwise gruff-seeming constable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's find out.

[The Chicago Manual of Style, section 7.15](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec015.html), says this:

> Capital letters used as words... usually form the plural by adding s. To aid comprehension, lowercase letters form the plural with an apostrophe and an s (compare “two as in llama” with “two a’s in llama”).

And it give the following example:

> the three Rs

So, if you must write your sentence like that, use "Hs."

Answer (score 10):

I prefer Hs or *H*s. Straightforward and not excessive. You do not use an apostrophe to make a plural.

I have seen people try to write out the letter, like "aitches," but that's hard for me to read.

Comment: @AN only my stubbornness. ;) Chicago and AP permit it; I think it looks awful.

Comment: *Ready Player One* did that and I didn't realize until like the last chapter the name "Aitch" was supposed to be "H"

Comment: Chicago allows an apostrophe when it's necessary for clarity. For example, the plural of "i" would be "i's" rather than "is."

Comment: If someone wrote the word "aitches" I would be thrown for a loop. I'd think the writer typoed itches and the editor let it through.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative path: instead of saying which letters were accented, give an example of a word which is altered.

> He had a thick accent, making his "house" into an "'ouse".

This only works when the accented sound can be represented in English text, of course (so no Germanic "ch" sounds).

Comment: The sound can't be represented in English. The "H" is pronounced kinda like you're trying to spit slime from out of your throat after a good cough.

Comment: @KlaraRaškaj: that might be a better thing to write - saying someone had a "thick accent" on one letter doesn't really convey an idea of *what sort* of accent; it's too vague to give an impression of how the character sounds. Whereas what you've written there is almost *too* clear :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would write **on his 'H's.** Single quotes around the letter.

---

Edit:

My reason is a matter of opinion, not grammar, I think this would make it the most likely to be read correctly, because the 'H' in single quotes would be read separately **as a letter** and no automatic attempt by the reader would be made to combine it with the 's', or misread that as a typo repetition of the word 'his', etc.

I understand this is contrary to the Chicago Manual of style, as an author of novels more interested in clarity of speech than grammatical correctness, I would still write it this way.

Comment: Single quotes are used in British English; double quotes are used in American English.

Answer (score 0):

How about "on his H sounds" ?

Technically speaking his accent doesn't appear in combinations like -gh or -ch.
It might be better to illustrate it with an example 'happy, with a guttural H' or whatever.